# What attributes does a good reliable beginner kayak have?

Tags: gear, kayaks

My Wife and I are looking into getting into recreational kayaking, no rapids or anything. Trying to find a good reliable Kayak that we both can get. We are looking for a sit in and ideally with some storage space.

What should we look for? Is there anything we should avoid?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TGO @BBrocker. It's generally not desired to ask for specific items to buy because they change from year to year so this topic will be obsolete quickly. It would be better to ask e.g. "What do I have to look for in a kayak as a beginner?".

Comment: I have edited the question so it should now be in scope.

Comment: Putting this in a comment since my knowledge is limited. The flatter it is on the bottom, the tougher it will be tip to over. Shorter kayaks are also easier to maneuver but don't track as well. It would be good to know where you're planning on taking them, lakes, the ocean, etc. I would suggest once you buy one, taking it to a calm lake and purposely tipping it over with yourself inside to practice both flipping it back over and getting back inside it in the water. It will help prevent panic if/when you unintentionally flip it over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you specify you don't look for a whitewater kayak?

Other than that the use you will do, and expect of doing in the future, of the kayak will be a big part of your choice: a little calm inland lake and sea will call for two different kayaks.
My suggestion to beginners is always to try as many as you can, through renting, dealers demo days, clubs and gatherings.
There should be a little bit of homework you need to do about kayak characteristics before going to buy something, learning about the meaning of terms like stability (primary and secondary), tracking, rocker, what is a skeg and what is a rudder and why they are there or not, etc etc. All together they will make you understand a bit how the kayak works and what you want to have or not. It will also help in understanding if a salesman is trying to find something that suits you or something that suits his commission.

Generally speaking you have a couple of extremes, on one side there's the performance boat, it's designed to respond readily to the paddler and a beginner will find it very nervous, impossible to have it do what they want. At the opposite side there are some models that are designed to take absolutely everybody in the water, they are not maneuverable at all, the bottom is very flat, difficult to capsize. They cost little but they also do very little for you, they will not improve your skills and they won't offer any room for you to grow. The problem with not improving your skills is that all is good in calm and flat days but sometimes being a better paddler helps in getting out of some uncomfortable situations.
It was mentioned that flat bottomed kayaks are more stable, that's true, that's because that shape will always try to follow the water surface. The problem with that is that when you are in waves that same extreme stability works against you as it will tend to follow the surface of the waves. A kayak **a bit** more unstable, while might seem tippy at first, is less affected by the waves and you will get used to it quickly enough (sometimes you might find yourself in bad weather, even if you have been careful, other times other boats could put you in a difficult situation).

Don't pay too much attention to things like speed, what you really want is to look for efficiency. For that same reason, unless you and your wife have the same size, she might like better a kayak slightly smaller than yours.

Consider used boats too, the prices are often low for kayaks that are in very good conditions, and at the beginning price is something to consider as there are a lot of other things you need to buy beside the kayak. Older models also have so many reviews online you can get a bit of an idea about them before even trying them (obviously every review is to be taken with a grain of salt).

Look for courses in your area, beside learning the basics in a proper **and safe** way they will clear your ideas on the kind of kayaks around, make you connect with other fellow kayakers, point you towards some good used kayaks.

Also take into account your space for storing the kayaks and how to transport them: sometimes one can't get what they want because they don't have enough room.

Think about a kayak as a pair of shoes, you cant really have one shoe to do everything,this is the same, there are tons of different models out there, if you start building your own they get even more. As a beginner you might not have a clear idea of how you will use the kayak, a bit because you might expect something different from what you actually get to do, or because you end with friends that steer you towards one activity rather than the other. Give yourself some options, don’t spend thousands right of the bat, try try try

PS: if you decide to just learn some things by yourself do it safely.

Comment: Anything on SOT vs SIS? Or would that deserve a question on its own?

Comment: @Roflo a SOT is great for beginners (our first kayaks were SOT because we're not doing white water, just lakes and calm sea with the dog) mainly because you don't have to learn to capsize and exit the kayak, which can be unnerving for some. Also Erik you don't need two different kayaks for lake and sea, there are mixes, depends how far out to sea you want to go before you should consider sea kayaks specifically.

Comment: @Aravona, I dont agree, an inland small lake that is protected desnt need the seagoing abilities of open water like the Great Lakes or the sea. Also going to poke around along the shore of small lakes, full of weeds etc is not great with a long sea kayak. If a 12 footer plastic tubbie from the big box stores can do all you want in calm waters then its fine there, in open water there are more appropriate hulls. Open water can get nasty even close to shore. Kayaks are always a compromise of characteristic, there isnt a do-it-all unfortunately. Although the old Mariner Coaster gets pretty close

Comment: @Roflo, SOT vs SIS depends on preferences, usage, climate too. When diving from a kayak having a SOT is great, some are wonderful to play in waves. If you are in a cold climate then SIS is better, and to some extent it offers sun protection too, etc etc... the list can be long and end even with the simple fact that some like one more than the other

Comment: @Roflo, I dont think it would do well as a question. There is a lot that is opinion based when it comes between the two types. The best thing is to learn the difference between the two kinds. As i understand you wont build your own and just buy one, that limits you to the models on the market and they have all their own behaviour, pick the one that suits you best.

Comment: Oh, I was just asking if it was a good idea to include something about SOT vs SIS in your (already great) answer. Personally I learned on a SIS and didn't even realize SOT existed till some time later. Never got used to them.

Comment: @Roflo, got it. I avoided as for a beginner both can do very well... would call for long discussions putting one against the other I think. If you want to post the question try, at the worst they will close it

Comment: @ErikvanDoren You certainly do not need a 12 foot kayak to go on the sea by any means - if you are going a few hundred yards from the coast on calm waters you do not need a 12ft sea kayak but 9 foot long and wider SOTs are often used on the sea.

Comment: @Aravona, in an internet website I wouldnt suggest a beginner to try kayaking in the sea on a short stubby kayak on their own. Theres the chance that they end further out they wanted and a beginner has difficulty in making a short kayak go straight to shore, they end getting tired. Add a bit of wind and current pushing out and you have to go tow them back. Its all good if the water is flat like oil and theres no wind but beginners make mistakes, they misjudge distances, currents, weather conditions so should look for something safe and well behaved in not perfect conditions

Comment: @ErikvanDoren well a lot of sea going kayaks aren't 12ft long. I also wouldn't call 9ft stubby? I'm certainly not saying go out on the sea in a say 6ft SI kayak. But many sea going SOTs are 9ft long, I know, I own two.

Comment: @Aravona, fishing SOT at 9ft lenght will be about 33 inches wide or more and they are indeed stubby. In wind and current a beginner would spend all its time and energy trying to stay pointed towards their destination. You might be able to squeeze all that the kayak has to offer out of it but a beginner has a very limited set of skills and they arent happy in open sea with something that doesnt track very well.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren actually I only had a weeks worth of experience in SI before buying my own SOT. I think perhaps a misunderstandig here then as stubby means short, not thin which you appear to be implying with your last comment. 9ft isn't stubby so far as length for some sea kayaks which are designed for less than a hundred yards out to see as I originally said, still sea going but more shore.

Comment: @Aravona, different strokes for different folks. These things are some of the reasons I told the OP he has homework to do and try as many kayaks as he can first.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren very true indeed! :)